# Error:(3) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android, xml

This is my xml file inside then anim folder. When I run the app then an error in parsing is shown.

shake.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
< translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:interpolator="@anim/cycle_7"
    android:toXDelta="5%" />
</set>
```

cycle_7.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
< cycleInterpolator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:cycles="7" />
</set>
```

Comment: You can see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[IT People Always Welcome](http://itpeoplealwayswelcome.blogspot.in/2013/09/how-to-make-your-users-aware-of.html) Here you find full code that you are looking for.

## shake.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="5%" android:duration="1000" android:interpolator="@anim/cycle_7" />
```

## cycle_7.xml

```
<cycleInterpolator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:cycles="7" />
```

## How to Use:

```
private void showError() {
      Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);
      mEditText.startAnimation(shake);
}
```

### Edited:

1. I think You have **space** between `<` and `translate` if you have copied code. Check it out.
2. `<set>` is not required as i have run demo with my above code its working fine.

Thank you. May this will helpful you.

Comment: No there is no problem in two xml's. May you have another problem in other xml. can you post Screenshots?

Comment: Thank you..........actuaally there was space between < and translate. Thank you...........

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a closing `</set>` tag.

*(+, delete that extra `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` line from the inner elements)*